# Binary Search Tree Forgetting Every Node I Add

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

My problem is seemingly simple, but I can't find its solution. I have a binary tree, and this is my add function:

```
void collection::addToTree(vendor *& item)
{
    Node * curr = root;
    while (curr)
    {
        if (strcmp(item->getName(), root->item->getName()) < 0)
            curr = curr->left;
        else
            curr = curr->right;
    }
    curr = new Node(item);
}
```

And this is my `Node` constructor:

```
collection::Node::Node(vendor *& item) : left(nullptr), right(nullptr)
{
    this->item = item;
}
```

However, the tree is always empty, no matter what or how many items I try to add to it. The only other piece of code I can think of that will help you guys is my `struct` for my tree:

```
struct Node
{
    Node();
    Node(vendor *& item);
    vendor * item;
    Node *left, *right;
};
Node * root;
```

All of the sub-variables of `vendor` do have values (as I've seen in my debugger). I wish I could give you guys more detail, but this is all I know about the error. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why does `int main() {int x = 7; int y = x; y = 8; cout << x;}` print 7 instead of 8?

Comment: You're modifying a local variable, `curr`,  which is ... local, so that's a change that can't be observed outside the function. (Why does the function take a *reference* to a pointer?)

Comment: @molbdnilo It works for linked lists.

Comment: @LarryK No, it doesn't. No assignment to a local variable has any effect on anything outside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the left/right pointers directly, something like this:

```
void collection::addToTree(vendor *& item)
{
    Node * curr = root;
    while (curr)
    {
        if (strcmp(item->getName(), curr->item->getName()) < 0)
        {
            if (!curr->left)
            {
                curr->left = new Node(item);
                return;
            }
            curr = curr->left;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!curr->right)
            {
                curr->right = new Node(item);
                return;
            }
            curr = curr->right;
        }
    }
    root = new Node(item);
}
```

Also, make sure you do `Node * root = nullptr`, as no initializing it can lead to it containing any arbitrary value.

Notice that I also changed `if (strcmp(item->getName(), root->item->getName()) < 0)` to `if (strcmp(item->getName(), curr->item->getName()) < 0)`, as the branching is dependent on `curr`, not `root`.

Comment: Good catch, didn't see that root on the comparison.

Comment: Why? When I want to add a node to a linked list, I have no problem traversing the list until `curr` is at a `nullptr` and then setting that to the new node. Also your code will overwrite `root` if `root` already has data in it. And if your solution was right, wouldn't my current function be able to add data to `root`?

Comment: I have a feeling you're misunderstanding pointers here, so I'll work it out. Since `curr` is a local variable, updating it directly does NOT update the tree. It's simply a pointer to some value in the tree. When you do `curr = curr->left;` you are saying *curr now points to the same that thing that the original curr->left pointed to*. So, if `curr` is *0x808080* and `curr->left`, at *0x808084*, points to *0x909090*, `curr` then becomes *0x909090*. So, then doing `curr = new Node(item);` doesn't change the data at *0x909090*, it simply updates `curr` to point to whatever was returned.

Comment: Also as per this comment: *Also your code will overwrite root if root already has data in it.* This is wrong. If `root` has data in it and the tree is not malformed, the function will return from one of the two inner-most branches. The final statement only gets touched when `curr` evaluates to `null` or `nullptr`, which won't happen in a well-formed tree unless it is empty.

Comment: @NickCano I didn't notice those return statements in your function. Also, you might add what you said in that first comment to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

In the `add` function, you're making only `curr` point to the new item, but that does not change back the previous left/right pointers, which probably is what you were aiming at.

Comment: What? Why would I need to change the left and right pointers? Also, I can't even add to root, which has no previous left or right pointer.

Comment: Aren't you adding it to a tree? So to add a new leaf you need to make one of the previous leaves' left or right pointers point to the new item. Like you said, you can't even add to root because it's just creating the node making nothing point to it. When adding the first item (other than the root), the root's left or right members will point to this new item.

Comment: They already point to the next pointer since I'm traversing the tree using the left and right pointers.

Comment: @LarryK What line of code do you think modifies the tree? Be as specific as you can.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `curr = new Node(item);`

Comment: The modifies `curr` to point to a newly-allocated node (instead of pointing to part of the tree). It has no effect on the tree. Right after that, you `return` and never do anything with the new value of `curr`.

Comment: This like makes only `curr` point to the new item. If it worked like you're thinking it would, the whole tree traversal would be broken, as the assignments to `curr` from left and right would change the previous left and right.

Comment: To be clear, when you assign something _to a pointer_, you don't change what was _pointed to_ by that pointer. So, when you do `curr = new Item`, you're saying: "curr, forget everything you pointed to, now you will point to this new item". You're not filling what it was pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that your `curr` variable should be declared as `Node **curr` and receive the root's address in order for the change to be visible outside of the `addToTree` function.

```
void collection::addToTree(vendor *& item)
{
    Node ** curr = &root;
    while (*curr)
    {
        if (strcmp(item->getName(), (*curr)->item->getName()) < 0)
            (*curr) = (*curr)->left;
        else
            (*curr) = (*curr)->right;
    }
    *curr = new Node(item);
}
```

Comment: Is this more or less efficient than the answer @NickCano gave? It certainly seems to require fewer operations, but a pointer to a pointer takes more memory if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I did some quick testing using `sizeof()` and found out that both pointers have the same size.